# Выводятся не все результаты в запросе с COUNT + LEFT JOIN

Tags: база-данных, mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы
1) Контакты

```
id | Name
```

2) Родственники

```
id | Contact1 (контакт первый) | Contact2 (второй) | Family (кем приходится)
```

На 1 контакта может быть сколько угодно связей. Надо при выводе контактов выводить, если у этого контакта родственные связи.

```
SELECT contact.id, contact.name, COUNT(fam.id) FROM contact LEFT JOIN fam on contact.id = fam.contact or contact.id = fam.contact2 GROUP BY fam.id ORDER BY contact.name
```

Возникает проблема: все работает, но в базе 743 контакта, а выводится максимум 50.

Comment: Похоже что шикарно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а если в GROUP BY добавить contact.id и contact.name, а fam.id убрать?

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
SELECT contact.id, contact.name, COUNT(fam.id) FROM contact 
LEFT JOIN fam on contact.id = fam.contact1 or contact.id = fam.contact2 
GROUP BY contact.id, contact.name 
ORDER BY contact.name
```